# Add New Row to SlickGrid

Tags: slickgrid

Hi i have tried these two codes for inserting a new row in slickgrid.

code-1:

```
data1.push({id: "12345", name: "secKey", field: "secKey", complete:true});
        //grid1.setData(data1);
        //grid1.render();
```

it is inserting as undefined in the slick grid cell..

code-2:

```
 try{
            var rowData = grid1.getData();
            //alert(rowData+"rowdata");

            newId = dataView1.getLength();
            //alert(newId);
            newRow.id = newId + 1;
            //alert(newRow.id);
            var newRow = {title: "new Title"};
            //alert(newRow);
            dataView1.insertItem(newRow.id, newRow);
            alert("end");
            }catch(e){
                alert("error:"+e.description);
            }
```

the code-2 catches and gives error..let me know wat i have to do code change.!

Comment: What is the error? What does your column specification look like?

Comment: @Ates Goral:error is undefined is null or not an object;my column specification look like as follows var columns = [ { id: "secKey", name: "secKey", field: "secKey", sortable: true,formatter:sectionLinkFormatter} ];

Answer (score 10):

You can do it as follows if you are using dataview,

```
function AddNewRow() {
    dataView.addItem({id: "12345", name: "secKey", field: "secKey", complete:true});
    dataView.refresh();
}
```

or you can do it as follows if you are not using dataview,

```
    function AddNewRow() {
        grid.getData().splice(grid.getDataLength(), 1, {});
        grid.invalidateRow(grid.getSelectedRows());
        grid.updateRowCount();
        grid.render();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Slick.DataView, you should use the `.addItem` method

```
dataView.beginUpdate();
dataView.addItem(item);
dataView.endUpdate();
```

Comment: @jatin patil i tried ur code, undefined is inserted. and in ur code2 where to specify the data to be inserted..? kavun ur code also inserts undefined

Comment: I got working by ths code...let me know any suggestions of using this code...data1[data1.length] = {
             id:data1.length+Math.random(),
             secKey:$('#sectionButtonName').val()             
            };
      grid1.setData(data1);
      grid1.render();

Comment: in the above code , filter is not working.wat should i do now?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I used Jatin's answer (without dataview):

```
slickgrid.onAddNewRow.subscribe(function (e, args) {
        var newRow = args.item;
        newRow.prop1= true;
        newRow.prop2= false;
        newRow.prop3= 0;
        newRow.prop4= "";

        args.grid.getData().splice(args.grid.getDataLength(), 1, newRow);
        args.grid.invalidateRow(args.grid.getDataLength() - 1);
        args.grid.updateRowCount();
        args.grid.render();
    });
```